# Is it possible, given a resource name, to find in which fragment is used?

Tags: android, android-fragments

We have an app that has been localized for different countries.
The client now is asking if we could make a version of the app where, for example in a search bar in the main activity, the tester enters the name of a string and the app brings the user to the actual screen where it is used.
So I was thinking if it would be possible to retrieve the fragment that is using that string (R.string.somestring), in that case I'd be able to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible but you can use switch statement to call that particular fragment

```
switch("name"){
      case "John":
           loadFragment(new FragmentName);
           break;
      case "Micheal"
           loadFragment(new FragmentName);
           break;
}
```

in load fragment

```
  private void loadFragment(Fragment fragments) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container, fragments);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Like that you can manually load the fragment.

Comment: my problem is I don't know the relation between "name" and "john". I know how to load fragment

Comment: Here "name" is the resource that you have mentioned. While searching when the result arrives match that result with switch case statement and load the particular fragment. There is no other way to find in which fragment the string is used.